# How to mock chained methods when dealing with thirdparty objects

Tags: java, mockito

My code looks like below

```
public void getEmployeeDetails(Employee employee){
 Employeecredentials credentials= employee.getCredentials();
}
```

the getCredentials method will be as follows

```
void getCredentials(){
  EmployeeCredentials employeecredentials= ThirdpartyClass().thirdpartyMethodB().thirdpartyMethodc().getCredentials
  return employeecredentials;
}
```

How do I mock the above method chain.

I tried

```
employeeCredentials.setcredentials("ADDFFF")
when(ThirdpartyClass().thirdpartyMethodB().thirdpartyMethodc().getCredentials).thenReturn(employeeCredentials);
```

But I get null pointer exception on the method chain. What am I missing

Comment: is that a static call on the 3rd party class?

Comment: What does `ThirdpartyClass()` do? Compileable example would be good.

Comment: Why dont you move   `ThirdpartyClass().thirdpartyMethodB().thirdpartyMethodc().getCredentials` to a new method and mock that method ?

Comment: @Nkosi: yes its a static call.

Comment: @bharathp: The thripartyClass provides us credentails, its just oneline of code existing in out application and we cannot change it

Comment: @J123 I meant you refactor your code so that you write a new method, something like `getCredFromThirdParty(){ThirdpartyClass().thirdpartyMethodB().thirdpartyMethodc().getCredentials}` and now you mock as following `when(getCredFromThirdParty()).thenReturn(employeeCredentials)` .

Comment: @bharathp: I got what you said but I cant change the code now. I am just moking the behaviour